# Wordpress youtube embed not clickable bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

After I moved a Wordpress website to production server I noticed youtube embeds were no longer clickable. The image and play button show up but nothing more.

Tried to renew the embed code, using the build in embed function, embed via media browser,... Nothing is working and it's making me crazy.

After some trial and error things I noticed that the video does work when the main bootstrap.css file is removed. Can't seem to find a clue to the solution though.

EDIT

---

Yes, I tried to disable all the plugins, with no result.
Changing back to the default twenty fifteen theme results in a working video embed. But since that one isn't build on bootstrap it's just a logic fact.

---

Anyone seen this before?

Web page with video embedded: [click here](http://sibe.be/basketfinale-2014-2015/)

Comment: Installing the Google Cast plugins stops sending errors to console but it's still not working. When removing the bootstrap.css it does work but yeah, not really how it should be ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the wordpress loop on the single.php page.
A wrong code snippet caused the issue.

Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

The website is sending lots of error messages in he consolu use F12 in Chrome, apparently your www-embed-player-new.js is causing the problem. Not even Edge is running the site correctly. I think you need a Chrome extension to make it work.

I would recommend you changing the plugin that imports the videos. Check this [enter link description here](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=)

EDIT:
The chrome plugin Google Cast stops the error messages but still doesn't work.

Comment: Strange... Since I'm not using a plugin for the embed functionallity. It is plain Wordpres implementation. The only reason I can realise is the fact that I change wp security settings between the working and not working youtube play. I didn't change the theme at all betweeen the working and non working version.